# Switch between fragment container and ViewPager as seen in the Youtube app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, youtube

I'd imagine that the youtube app uses both the [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java)
and the [SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java) in conjunction with a ViewPager in the "What to watch" section. In the "My Subscriptions" section of the Youtube app a fragment container is probably used.

How do you switch between a ViewPager and a fragment container?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution was right in front of my eyes.

If you look at tutorials for creating the 5.0 tabs they all say to put the code inside of the main activity. The way I did it was to include the code inside of a fragment, with its own xml layout. That way you are always using the fragment container and the ViewPager will never interfere with the fragment container.